# when i use position:absolute in child block it does not refer parent block?

Tags: html, css

In HTML,When you use the position:absolute css property in child block the absolute value is not taken from parent tag it refer from whole browser window.
the sample code is shown below..

**CSS**

```
.parent {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Why are you asking this question if you already know the answer? Anyone who even looks for the most basic `position:absolute` search query on Google will find that you need a `relative` container (or other non-`static`). The way I see it, you only asked this question to farm reputation from the system - you've gained 55 already!

Comment: @Kolink: Posting a question that you know the answer to and then answering it is fine, but you're right in that this is a really basic and frequently asked question that can be answered with a simple Google search.

Comment: @Kolink it seems this is a kind of spam!

Comment: @Kolink I post this to share my knowledge.

Comment: @ABFORCE: Spam has a very specific meaning. This is not spam.

Comment: @Rajkumar: Sharing your knowledge is fine, but this has been asked before. Please search the site to make sure your question hasn't already been asked and answered elsewhere before you post it yourself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want the arrange the child with in the parent block just add `position:relative` in the parent CSS

Answer (score 2):

The parent block needs to be have `position` set to a non-static value, that is: 
`position: absolute`, `position: fixed` or `position: relative`.

The value you need depends on the layout application.

Answer (score 1):

```
.parent {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    position:relative;/*this makes all my children s position relative to me */
}

.child {
    position: absolute;/* i have an absolute position and i am relative to my parent*/
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pGvvq/

markup:

```
<section class=parent>
    this makes all my children s position relative to me
    <article class=child>
        i have an absolute position and i am relative to my parent
    </article>
</section>
```

[image]

READ more http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/